# Is this 0-day RCE Exploit for Chrome fake?

Tags: exploit, chrome, zero-day

I found this guy claiming that he has a 0-day Exploit for Chrome, Firefox and Windows 10, but to me it seems to be fake...

[Video - 0day RCE Exploit for Google Chrome 59.0.3071.86](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DUHMhObmWdU)

Here is [video](https://ruclip.com/video/pqxCrAkBYno/0day-rce-exploit-for-google-chrome-5903071115.html) for newer version of Chrome 59.0.3071.115.

Description:

> 0day RCE Exploit for Google Chrome 59.0.3071.86
>
> Exploit Type: Remote code execution, Sandbox escape.
>
> Exploitation Parameters: Bypasses ASLR, Bypasses DEP / W ^ X, Bypasses
>   EMET Version 5.52±
>
> Privilege Level Gained: Medium

How can we be sure that this is not real? For me it looks to good to be true...

Comment: The only way to confirm this would be by knowing details of the vulnerability - which the author omitted for obvious reasons.

Comment: The second video at least look like an exploit. First video doesn't make sense at all

Comment: send me a PoC and I'll let you know ;P